# Django import messes up Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a django project with the following Django project structure:

```
project/
  ...
  some_app/
    __init__.py
    some_module_where_i_import_some_utils.py
  server/
    __init__.py
    settings/
      __init__.py
      common.py
      dev.py
      ...
    celery.py
    ...
  utils/
    __init__.py
    some_utils.py
  manage.py
  ...
```

When using utils I import them the following way:

```
from project.utils.some_utils import whatever
```

And it works well. However when I run celery worker using `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=server.settings.dev celery -A server worker --beat -l info` `autodiscover_tasks` fails with the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`.

Here are contents of `server/celery.py`:

```
import os

from celery import Celery


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "server.settings.prod")

app = Celery("server")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))
```

Here is `server/__init__.py`:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `celery.py` the following way did the job:

```
import os
import sys

from celery import Celery

sys.path.append("..")
...
```

I'm not sure if this could cause problems in the future and will continue looking into it and update the answer if I come up with something better.